# How do we define cartesian coordinates on a curved manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

Spacetime in general relativity is supposed to be curved, despite this we assume that cartesian coordinates still make sense (locally?), don't we? So it should be possible to define cartesian coordinates locally on a curved manifold (Riemannian manifold?), shouldn't it?

So the question is: how are cartesian coordinates defined on a curved manifold (Riemannian manifold?)? An example with cartesian cooridnates on a sphere will be appreciated :)

Comment: Any manifold, by definition, comes equipped with [_charts_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold#Coordinate_charts) which are essentially local cartesian coordinate systems

Comment: Are you familir with [manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold), their [coordinate charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Charts), and the easy six chart [atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Atlases) of the [sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Sphere_with_charts)?

Comment: Let's be careful. What do you mean by cartesian coordinates? Are you thinking that these are Euclidean coordinates (i.e., the metric is flat)?

Comment: I'm familiar with the basics of differential geomety (my bachelor thesis was about the general Stokes' theorem). I'm just wondering what we mean by "cartesian coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$" in general relativity i.e. on a curved (Riemannian) manifold.

Comment: They just mean a coordinate chart. That's all it could mean unless they're working in a manifold with zero curvature tensor.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a chart, but charts are different. They is surely a difference between cartesian coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$ and spherical coordinates $(t, r, \phi, \theta)$ isn't it? I'm wondering how is the former defined.

Comment: When you speak about "cartesian coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$", do you attach any specific significance to the choice of letters $t$, $x$, $y$ and $z$? For instance, if I started with $(t,x,y,z)$ but then decided instead to make the substitutions $r=x$, $\phi=y$, $\theta=z$, would it no longer be appropriate to refer to $(t,r,\phi,\theta)$ as Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Assuming the letters have their usual meaning, the difference between $(t,x,y,z)$ and $(t,r,\phi,\theta)$ is pretty much what Ted shifrin brought up. The (usual Riemannian) metric tensor has constant components when expressed in terms of the $(t,x,y,z)$ chart, while the components in the $(t,r,\phi,\theta)$ are not constant. However, in this case, it is because $\Bbb{R}^4$ is a flat manifold that we can locally (in this case globally) introduce such a chart where the components of the metric tensor are constant. If the manifold is not flat (btw "flat" has a technical meaning) then we can't.

Comment: Does it mean we cannot define cartesian coordinates on a curved manifold even locally?

Comment: In relativity theory, a local Galilean coordinate system for a point in spacetime is an orthogonal spacetime coordinate system whose Christoffel symbols vanish at the point considered. Maybe this notion of Galilean coordinate can help what you are looking for.

Comment: Try throwing away the curvature aspect and adhere to the charts.  With GR you have Cinf and local differential maps; i.e. tangent spaces that have an associated metric.  Local cartesian coordinates would be a Minkowski diagram with (as mentioned above) the first derivative of the Christoffel symbols vanishing.